# AWS lambda: Importing external python library using subprocess makes program too slow

Tags: python, aws-lambda, subprocess

My use case is:

I have to execute some python scripts on AWS Lambda.
I am using **subprocess.check_output** to execute those scripts and those works fine.
Problem arises when the scripts has some external dependencies (not on Lambda by default) e.g numpy.

So, I created my deployment package with the external libraries which now reside in **/opt/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages** and I am able to import them in my handler function.

But when I execute the scripts, my scripts were not able to find those libraries. So, I looked around and found out that subprocess doesn't preserve PYTHONPATH.

So, now I am passing env parameter to the subprocess.check_output, through which those scripts are able to find the libraries.

But the issue is, this makes the execution extremely slow. (e.g A program runs in 300 ms which doesn't have any external dependency import, but with external dependency import it takes 4883.81 ms).

My handler function looks like this:

```
import subprocess

def main(event, context):
    # Omitting creation of script.py in /tmp directory. 
    print(subprocess.Popen(["/usr/bin/python", "/tmp/script.py"], env={'PYTHONPATH': '/opt/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages'}).communicate())
```

Also tried:

1. Changing working directory  by `**cwd**` parameter.
2. Installing external dependencies in same folder as of handler function.
3. Tried with **subprocess.check_output** instead of **Popen**

Any lead is appreciated. Thanks in Advance.
Also please let me know, if you need any other information.

Edit: Above examples uses **lambda layer** for the python packages, But I have tried without lambda layer (where Python packages are in the same folder as of handler.py)

Comment: have you checked out the documentation? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-package.html and https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/build-python-lambda-deployment-package/

Comment: Hi @AnthonyKong yes, as I mentioned I am able to import python packages. So that is not an issue.

Comment: Check the second link in my comment. The location matters.

Comment: I have tried that as well, you are talking about the packages in same location as the handler function right?